# Disable DELETE on table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, sql-delete, audit

For a security sensitive design, I'd like to disable `DELETEs` on certain tables.

The `DELETE` should merely set a `deleted` flag on a row (which would be then visible on a view, which would be used by the application layer).

As I understand a [rule](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/rules.html) would generate additional queries - so a rule could not suppress the original query.

As illustration a toy example with a trigger (not yet tested):

```
-- data in this table should be 'undeletable'
CREATE table article (
    id serial,
    content text not null,
    deleted boolean default false
)

-- some view that would only show articles, that are NOT deleted
...

-- toy trigger (not tested)
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION suppress_article_delete()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $sad$
BEGIN
    IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
        UPDATE article SELECT id, content, TRUE;
        -- NEW or NULL??
        RETURN NEW;
    END IF;
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$sad$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

What would be a good way to suppress a `DELETE`?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> As I understand a rule would generate additional queries - so a rule could not suppress the original query.

Not really - it could be an [`INSTEAD`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/rules-update.html) rule:

```
 CREATE RULE shoe_del_protect AS ON DELETE TO shoe DO INSTEAD NOTHING;
```

(an example on that same page of the manual).

Another way is to `REVOKE` delete privileges on the table in question and to create stored procedure(s) for deleting... and updating and inserting also probably.

Comment: Thanks! I'd like to get this *undelete* design into the data-model, not the administration (revoke) - so I guess I'll try a `INSTEAD` rule.

Comment: The problem of a ON DELETE DO INSTEAD NOTHING is that code that issues a DELETE will not get notified that nothing happened - the DELETE will be successful for the client and silent errors can happen.

Comment: @peschü True. One way to avoid the problem:

`create or replace function raiseException() returns void language plpgsql volatile as $$ begin
  raise exception 'Cannot delete row.';
end$$;


CREATE or replace RULE prevent_deletes AS ON DELETE TO shoe
DO INSTEAD select raiseException();
`