# Is there a way to disable updates/deletes but still allow triggers to perform them?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, privileges

Basically, I want to be able to use the `REVOKE` command to disable `UPDATE` and `DELETE`, but I still want the triggers on a table to update my rows.

My triggers perform on newly inserted rows, and update a specific field. So I still want this behaviour, but wouldn't they be disabled with `REVOKE` or with a `RULE`. ([I saw an SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11298431/disable-delete-on-table-in-postgresql))

Is there a way to keep using the `UPDATE`/`INSERT` commands in `TRIGGERS` but disabling the rest?

Comment: If your trigger updates the rows, that are being inserted - it is a sign of a bad design. Can you show as some of your triggers or tell, what do you do with them?

Comment: If you need to `update a specific field` of an inserted record - you can just assign the desired value to `NEW.specific_field`. You do not need a separate update.

Comment: I didn't design it, but I don't know if I would have done anything better to be honest. I haven't looked at the triggers just yet. Maybe I could use this, I don't know. I'll let you know. Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

Triggers are run with the privileges of the trigger function, defaulting to `SECURITY INVOKER` which means, the trigger function is effectively executed with the privileges of the `current_user`, in your case the one inserting rows.

If the current user does not have the required privileges for the tables your trigger function operates on, your original operation in the underlying table will error out.

**However**, you can use [**`SECURITY DEFINER`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) for the trigger function to have this function run with the privileges of the `OWNER` of the function.

If you have a superuser *own* the trigger function, it can do *everything* - which would be a possible security hazard. Consider the instructions in the manual about [Writing `SECURITY DEFINER` Functions Safely](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html#SQL-CREATEFUNCTION-SECURITY).

But it's wiser to make a plain role with just the necessary privileges `OWNER` of the trigger function. You can even just create a "daemon" role without login, acting as privilege bundle for such operations. You would then grant only the needed privileges (on schemas, tables, sequences ...) to this daemon role. For more sophisticated designs you should bundle privileges in "group roles" (again, no login) and grant these group roles to roles that need it (to the daemon role in this example), effectively making them "member of the group". I do that a lot.

Consider this related answer on dba.SE concerning the privileges on the function itself:

- [What are the privileges required to execute a trigger function in PostgreSQL 8.4?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/46834/3684)

Comment: Thanks, that looks really good. The explanation you provided is great. I'll need to check that when I'll have a chance. Thanks again :)