# Allow only triggers to update a column

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, privileges

I have two tables, `t1(foo)` and `t2(bar)`, and a trigger on update `t2.bar` that updates `t1.foo` to something else.

At first I thought of just prohibiting any updates on `t1` by using a trigger before update on `t1.foo` that always throws an exception. However, wouldn't that also block changes from the first trigger?

How do I do this?

Comment: Are you trying to prevent access to tables with triggers? Don't do that. Use the built in security system (i.e. logins, roles etc)

Comment: That sounds like it could be a good answer if explained, along with some usage philosophy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a "daemon" role (a non-login role for this dedicated purpose) that owns the trigger function in combination with `SECURITY DEFINER` And grant the necessary privileges on `t1` to it.

Details in these related questions:
[Is there a way to disable updates/deletes but still allow triggers to perform them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886529/is-there-a-way-to-disable-updates-deletes-but-still-allow-triggers-to-perform-th/17887101#17887101)
[Allow insertion only from within a trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20151331/pl-pgsql-allow-insertion-only-from-within-a-trigger/20155754#20155754)