# Allow insertion only from within a trigger

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, insert, plpgsql

I'm new to SQL programming, and I couldn't find an answer to this question online.

I'm working with pl/pgsql and I wish to achieve the following result:

I have a table A with certain attributes.
I am supposed to keep this table updated at any time - thus whenever a change was made that can affect A's values (in other tables B or C which are related to A) - a trigger is fired which updates the values (in the process - new values can be inserted into A, as well as old values can be deleted).
At the same time, I want to prevent from someone insert values into A.

What I want to do is to create a trigger which will prevent insertion into A (by returning NULL) - but I **don't** want this trigger to be called when I'm doing the insertion from another Trigger - so eventually - insertion to A will only be allowed from within a specific trigger.

As I said before, I'm new to SQL, and I don't know if this is even possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, totally possible.

#### 1. Generally disallow `UPDATE` to `A`

I would operate with privileges:

```
REVOKE ALL ON TABLE A FROM public;  -- and from anybody else who might have it
```

That leaves superusers such as `postgres` who ignore these lowly restrictions. Catch those inside your trigger-function on `A` with [`pg_has_role()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-ACCESS-TABLE):

```
IF pg_has_role('postgres', 'member') THEN
   RETURN NULL;
END IF;
```

Where `postgres` is an actual superuser. Note: this catches other superusers as well, since they are member of every role, even other superusers.

You could catch non-superusers in a similar fashion (alternative to the `REVOKE` approach).

#### 2. Allow `UPDATE` for daemon role

Create a non-login role, which is allowed to update `A`:

```
CREATE ROLE a_update NOLOGIN;
-- GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA xyz TO a_update;  -- may be needed, too
GRANT UPDATE ON TABLE A TO a_update;
```

Create trigger functions on tables `B` and `C`, **owned** by this daemon role and with `SECURITY DEFINER`. Details:

- [Is there a way to disable updates/deletes but still allow triggers to perform them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886529/is-there-a-way-to-disable-updates-deletes-but-still-allow-triggers-to-perform-th/17887101#17887101)

Add to the trigger function on `A`:

```
IF pg_has_role('postgres', 'member') THEN
   RETURN NULL;
ELSIF pg_has_role('a_update', 'member') THEN
   RETURN NEW;
END IF;
```

For simple 1:1 dependencies, you can also work with [foreign key constraints (additionally) using `ON UPDATE CASCADE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK).