# To convert from Python arrays to PostgreSQL quickly?

Tags: python, arrays, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

This is a follow-up question to: [How to cast to int array in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107079/how-to-cast-to-int-array-in-postgresql)
I am thinking how to convert Python's datatype of array-array of signed integer into to `int` of PostgreSQL quickly:

```
import numpy as np; # use any data format of Python here
event = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]);
```

where `[]` should be replaced by `{}` and surrounded by `'` if manually. 
In PostgreSQL, the following is accepted as the syntax of the datatype

```
...
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insaft_function('{{1,2},{3,4}}');
```

### @JohnMee's suggestion

```
str(event).replace('[','{').replace(']','}').replace('\n ',',')
```

### @ErwinBrandstetter's suggestion

Stick to signed integers because it is supported by SQL standard. 
Map to `int`, so just in PostgreSQL side:

```
TG_ARGV::int[]
```

I want to stick to this Erwin's suggestion.

### Test run of simpler version of @ErwinBrandstetter's answer

I have to simplify his answer to keep it enough focused here by removing the table-name from function so just keeping the trigger for one initial table *measurements*:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_create_my_trigger(_arg0 text)
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
BEGIN
EXECUTE format($$
    DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS insaft_ids ON measurements;
    CREATE TRIGGER insaft_ids
    AFTER INSERT ON measurements
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insaft_function(%1$L)$$
    , _arg0
);

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And I run:

```
sudo -u postgres psql detector -c "SELECT f_create_my_trigger('[[1,2],[3,4]]');"
```

But get empty output:

```
 f_create_my_trigger 
---------------------

(1 row)
```

How can you map to `int` for PostgreSQL 9.4 in Python?

Comment: presumably a follow up to [this question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107079/how-to-cast-to-int-array-in-postgresql)

Comment: Do you just want the array massaged into that string format, or something more?

Comment: Presumably something more, can you clarify what you're having trouble with, tried, etc?  Because the string format is trivial... `str(event).replace('[','{').replace(']','}').replace('\n ',',')`

Comment: Careful with the data type **`unsigned integer`**. Standard Postgres only supports signed integer as defined in the SQL standard. You may want to map to `bigint` instead of `int` to avoid an overflow in the upper half. Or install the extension [**`pguint`** provided by Peter Eisentraut](https://github.com/petere/pguint).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Excellent comment! Then, I want to stick only to signed integer. How can you do this mapping from `bigint` to `int`?

Comment: The array literal stays the same, that's just a text representation. But cast to `bigint[]`, not `int[]` on the Postgres side. In [my previous answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/107086/3684) that would be `TG_ARGV[0]::bigint[]`. I can't comment on the NumPy part, since I don't use it.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter We can skip Numpy. I trust that you know the topic much better than me. How would you do the conversion from Python dataformat to PostgreSQL `bigint[]`?

Comment: Now that you've change your question to  "signed integer", you can map to plain `integer` in Postgres. I am not sure how to understand the updated question: `How can you map from bigint to int for the example of PostgreSQL 9.4 in Python?` I assume you have a 2-dimenstional array of (signed?) integer numbers in Python? Just make sure that numbers don't overflow. [Here are the specs for the discussed integer types in Postgres.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/datatype-numeric.html)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Thank you! My misunderstanding. So just keep in plain `integer` in Postgres. Assume 2-dimensional array of signed int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Setup

You want to create triggers (repeatedly?) using the same trigger function like outlined in [my related answer on dba.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/107086/3684). You need to pass values to the trigger function to create *multiple* rows with *multiple* column values, hence the two-dimensional array. (But we can work with *any* clearly defined string!)

The only way to pass values to a PL/pgSQL trigger function (other than column values of the triggering row) are `text` parameters, which are accessible inside the function as [0-based array of text in the special array variable `TG_ARGV[]`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-DML-TRIGGER). You can pass a variable number of parameters, but we discussed a single string literal representing your 2-dimenstional array earlier.

Input comes from a 2-dimensional Python array with **signed integer** numbers, that fits into the Postgres type `integer`. Use the Postgres type `bigint` to cover unsigned integer numbers, [as commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31533496/to-convert-from-python-arrays-to-postgresql-quickly#comment51258874_31533496).

The text representation in Python looks like this:

```
[[1,2],[3,4]]
```

Syntax for a Postgres array literal:

```
{{1,2},{3,4}}
```

And you want to automate the process.

#### Full automation

You can concatenate the string for the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement in your client or you can persist the logic in a server-side function and just pass parameters.

Demonstrating an example function taking a table name and the string that's passed to the trigger function. The trigger function [`insaft_function()` is defined in your previous question on dba.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/107086/3684).

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_create_my_trigger(_tbl regclass, _arg0 text)
  RETURNS void
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format($$
      DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS insaft_%1$s_ids ON %1$s;
      CREATE TRIGGER insaft_%1$s_ids
      AFTER INSERT ON %1$s
      FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insaft_function(%2$L)$$
                , _tbl
                , translate(_arg0, '[]', '{}')
      );
END 
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT f_create_my_trigger('measurements', '[[1,2],[3,4]]');
```

Or:

```
SELECT f_create_my_trigger('some_other_table', '{{5,6},{7,8}}');
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9c12b4a6242197901ba248d3064161a8)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b6f44/1)</sub>

Now you can pass either `[[1,2],[3,4]]` (with square brackets) or `{{1,2},{3,4}}` (with curly braces). Both work the same. `translate(_arg0, '[]', '{}'` transforms the first into the second form.

This function drops a trigger of the same name if it exists, before creating the new one. You may want to drop or keep this line:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS insaft_%1$s_ids ON %1$s;
```

This runs with the privileges of the calling DB role. You could make it run with superuser (or any other) privileges if need be. See:

- [Is there a way to disable updates/deletes but still allow triggers to perform them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886529/is-there-a-way-to-disable-updates-deletes-but-still-allow-triggers-to-perform-th/17887101#17887101)

There are many ways to achieve this. It depends on exact requirements.

#### Explaining [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT)

[`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) and the data type `regclass` help to safely concatenate the DDL command and make SQL injection impossible. See:

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)

The first argument is the "format string", followed by arguments to be embedded in the string. I use [dollar-quoting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12320729/939860), which is not strictly necessary for the example, but generally a good idea for concatenating long strings containing single-quotes: **`$$DROP TRIGGER ... $$`**

`format()` is modeled along  the C function `sprintf`. **`%1$s`** is a format specifier of the [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) function. It means that the first (`1$`) argument after the format string is inserted as *unquoted string* (`%s`), hence: `%1$s`. The first argument to format is `_tbl` in the example - the `regclass` parameter is rendered as legal identifier automatically, double-quoted if necessary, so `format()` does not have to do more. Hence just `%s`, not `%I` (identifier). Read the linked answer above for details.
The other format specifier in use is **`%2$L`**: Second argument as *quoted string literal*.

If you are new to `format()`, play with these simple examples to understand:

```
SELECT format('input -->|%s|<-- here', '[1,2]')
     , format('input -->|%s|<-- here', translate('[1,2]', '[]', '{}'))
     , format('input -->|%L|<-- here', translate('[1,2]', '[]', '{}'))
     , format('input -->|%I|<-- here', translate('[1,2]', '[]', '{}'));
```

And [read the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT).

Comment: I included my test run in the body of the question. I simplified it to one single table, since having some trouble with this `_%s$s`. However, I also included now in the test run three more indexes in parameters. I do not know if this is wise. Or should everything be just a string? Now having _arg0 to _arg3.

Comment: @Masi: You can pass as many parameters as you like as long as it works for your trigger function. But don't confuse references to function parameters with the "format specifier" of `format()`. I added a chapter to explain. *Follow the links for details.*

Comment: Can you please explain the following part more? `format($$ ... FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insaft_function(%2$L)$$, _tbl, translate(_arg0, '[]', '{}') );` You apply `format` first to the table name. Earlier I had `FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insaft_function(1, 2, 3, '{{1,2},{3,4}}'); ` where the function has 4 parameters. In your example, there seems to be only one parameter with `insaft_function`. `translate` is apparently run after the function.

Comment: I made a minimum example of your code in the body of question where I get an empty output.

Comment: @Masi: `translate()` is applied on the input parameter `_arg0` *before* feeding the result of this expression as parameter to `format()`. The function `f_create_my_trigger()` is *expected* to return nothing, it is defined with `RETURNS void`. It (re-)creates a *trigger* on table `measurements` that inserts rows in table `event` after every insert to measurements. You need to understand what functions, triggers and trigger functions are before you proceed with this complex task. Are you even sure you need a trigger?

Comment: Returning thing can be better. Still revieving it to the trigger implementation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have done several tests based on your answer. I gave you full credits because otherwise this thread would expand a lot easily. I instead opened a new thread with better focus on BEFORE INSERT here http://stackoverflow.com/q/31774157/54964 where the chain of events is less.