# To ignore result in BEFORE TRIGGER of PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

This thread is a part challenge of this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31533496/54964) to which I am searching a better solution for one part by BEFORE TRIGGER. 
I just want to launch a trigger to convert to correct brackets. 
I am thinking whether I should return from the trigger NULL or something else in before trigger.

Code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insbef_events_function() 
    RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$func$
DECLARE
    m int[]; 
BEGIN
   FOREACH m SLICE 1 IN ARRAY TG_ARGV[0]::int[]
   LOOP
      INSERT INTO events (measurement_id, event_index_start, event_index_end) 
      SELECT NEW.measurement_id, m[1], m[2];  -- Postgres array starts with 1 !
   END LOOP;

      -- do something with _result ...

RETURN NULL; -- result ignored since this is an BEFORE trigger TODO right?
END 
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

which I use the by the function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_create_my_trigger_events(_arg1 int, _arg2 text, _arg3 text)
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
BEGIN

EXECUTE format($$
    DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS insbef_ids ON events
    CREATE TRIGGER insbef_ids
    BEFORE INSERT ON events
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insbef_events_function(%1$L)$$
    , translate(_arg2, '[]', '{}'), translate(_arg3, '[]', '{}')
);

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I am unsure about this line: `RETURN NULL; -- result ignored since this is an`BEFORE`trigger TODO right?`, since I think this is the case in `AFTER` trigger but not in before trigger.
I just want to launch a trigger to convert correct brackets.

Test command is `sudo -u postgres psql detector -c "SELECT f_create_my_trigger_events(1,'[112]','[113]');"` getting the following error because of misunderstanding of the returning -thing, I think.

> ```
> LINE 3:     CREATE TRIGGER insbef_ids
>             ^
> QUERY:  
>     DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS insbef_ids ON events
>     CREATE TRIGGER insbef_ids
>     BEFORE INSERT ON events
>     FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insbef_events_function('{112}')
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function f_create_my_trigger_events(integer,text,text) line 4 at EXECUTE statement
> ```

How can you manage `BEFORE` triggers in PostgreSQL 9.4?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Yes, yours! I took some days in testing your suggestions in different settings and they worked but forgot to accept your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you need to pass the row variable in a **`BEFORE`** trigger. Passing `NULL` cancels the operation for the row:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insbef_events_function() 
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$func$
DECLARE
   m int[]; 
BEGIN
   FOREACH m SLICE 1 IN ARRAY TG_ARGV[0]::int[]
   LOOP
      INSERT INTO events (measurement_id, event_index_start, event_index_end) 
      SELECT NEW.measurement_id, m[1], m[2];  -- Postgres array subscripts start with 1
   END LOOP;

      -- do something with _result ...

   RETURN NEW;  -- NULL would cancel operation in BEFORE trigger!
END 
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I demonstrated the use of `RETRUN NULL` in an `AFTER` trigger [in my previous answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/107086/3684). You can't do the same for a `BEFORE` trigger. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html)

> Row-level triggers fired `BEFORE` can return null to signal the trigger
> manager to skip the rest of the operation for this row (i.e.,
> subsequent triggers are not fired, and the `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` does
> not occur for this row). If a nonnull value is returned then the
> operation proceeds with that row value.

There is more. Read the manual.

But since you are passing two 1-dimensional arrays instead of one 2-dimensional array now, you need to adapt your trigger logic:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insbef_events_function() 
    LANGUAGE plpgsql RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$func$
DECLARE
   a1 int[] := TG_ARGV[1]::int[];
   a2 int[] := TG_ARGV[2]::int[];
BEGIN
   FOR i in array_lower(a1, 1) .. array_upper(a1, 1)
   LOOP
      INSERT INTO events (measurement_id, event_index_start, event_index_end) 
      SELECT NEW.measurement_id  -- or TG_ARGV[0]::int instead?
           , a1[i], a2[i];
   END LOOP;

   RETURN NEW;  -- NULL would cancel operation in BEFORE trigger!
END 
$func$;
```

It's your responsibility that both arrays have the same number of elements.
The function changing the trigger could look like this now:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_create_my_trigger_events(_arg1 int, _arg2 text, _arg3 text)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql RETURNS void AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format(
    $$DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS insbef_ids ON measurements; -- on measurements ..
      CREATE TRIGGER insbef_ids
      BEFORE INSERT ON measurements  -- .. according to previous posts!!
      FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insbef_events_function(%s, %L, %L)$$
    , _arg1
    , translate(_arg2, '[]', '{}')
    , translate(_arg3, '[]', '{}')
   );
END
$func$;
```

You need to understand basics of SQL, PL/pgSQL, trigger functions and array handling before using this advanced automated design.