# Putting timestamp in a COMMENT ON TABLE

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, dynamic-sql, ddl, postgresql-9.4

I'm regularly re-creating a table in PostgreSQL (9.4.1), much like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test.foo;
CREATE TABLE test.foo AS
  SELECT * FROM test.dagi_kommune
  WHERE ST_Area(wkb_geometry) < 500;
```

I would like to add a comment to the table, stating when the table was created. There are no problem creating a basic comment, like this:

```
COMMENT ON TABLE test.foo IS 'Table create date: ';
```

And I can also generate a independent time stamp, like this:

```
SELECT to_char(LOCALTIMESTAMP, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS');
```

But if I try to put the time stamp into the comment, like this:

```
COMMENT ON TABLE test.foo IS to_char(LOCALTIMESTAMP, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS');
```

I get the following response:

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "to_char"
> LINE 10: COMMENT ON TABLE test.foo IS to_char(LOCALTIMESTAMP, 'YYYY-M...
>                                   ^
>
> ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: syntax error at or near "to_char"
> SQL state: 42601
> Character: 276
> ```

How can I get a current 'date and time' stamped into the table's comment?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to build and execute the statement as dynamic SQL.

```sql
DO
$do$
BEGIN
EXECUTE 'COMMENT ON TABLE b2 IS ''Table create date: '
     || to_char(LOCALTIMESTAMP, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')
     || '''';
END
$do$
```

Plain concatenation is safe in this case, for unsafe input, use [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) accordingly. See:

- [Error when setting n_distinct using a plpgsql variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36025308/error-when-setting-n-distinct-using-a-plpgsql-variable/36025963#36025963)
- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)
- [To convert from Python arrays to PostgreSQL quickly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31533496/to-convert-from-python-arrays-to-postgresql-quickly/31667372#31667372)

Line breaks are optional. The same as one-liner for scripting:

```
DO $do$BEGIN EXECUTE 'COMMENT ON TABLE b2 IS ''Table create date: ' || to_char(LOCALTIMESTAMP, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') || ''''; END $do$;
```

Comment: Thanks. It's sort of clumsy, like in too many lines, for the use I had in mind. It would considerably clutter my SQL scripts. But now I know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you will be executing your commands using `psql` the following is a clean and concise method using psql variables to add a timestamp:

```sql
SELECT current_timestamp AS now
\gset
COMMENT ON TABLE test.foo IS :'now';
```

My preferred way to add additional text to the comment is as follows, using `\set` to concatenate:

```sql
SELECT current_timestamp AS now
\gset
\set comment :now 'text'
COMMENT ON TABLE test.foo IS :'comment';
```

I have not found an effective way to concatenate another string in the COMMENT command, since it expects one string literal.

Comment: Thanks for your a  reply, but the project was finished some years back...

Comment: Understood. It was intended more for those who arrive here in the future.

Comment: Can i concatenate this with some more text? Like 'Current time was: _variable_'

Answer (score 0):

Enhancing Spencer's comment above:

```
SELECT current_timestamp as dump_time
\gset
COMMENT ON SCHEMA my_schema IS 'Latest dump at: ':'dump_time';
```

Comment: This adds an extra single quote, resulting in `Latest dump at: 'YYYY-MM-DD`.  It isn't clear why it works, but I don't think it's being parsed the way you expect.