# Postgresql rule for suppressing 'DELETE FROM table' in some cases

Tags: postgresql, sql-delete, rule

I have two tables in my db: `order` and `deliveries`. When creating order, I generate at the same time a number of deliveries depending on the order's start and end dates.

Deliveries have boolean `done` field, that is checked when the delivery is done. I have to suppress deleting any order if it has any deliveries that are done -otherwise the deliverer will loose the data (f.ex. delivery weight), as such info is stored in the `order`. Only in the case that none of deliveries is done, I can delete them together with the order.
In such case I can use rules ([Disable DELETE on table in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11298431/disable-delete-on-table-in-postgresql)), but it seems not to work in my case: "syntax error close to IF". **Are rules good here? Why can't I get my `IF-THEN` statement working?**

```
CREATE RULE delete_order AS ON DELETE TO orders DO INSTEAD
(
    DELETE FROM deliveries WHERE (order = OLD.id AND done = false);
    IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM deliveries WHERE order = OLD.id)) THEN
            DELETE FROM orders WHERE id = OLD.id;
    ELSE
            RAISE NOTICE 'Cannot delete order that is partially done.';
    END IF;
)
```

Comment: The question needs table definitions for involved tables (`\d tbl` in psql) and the version of Postgres.

Comment: Use ON DELETE RESTRICT in your foreign key definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are better off writing a trigger function here.

```
CREATE FUNCTION delete_order () RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM deliveries WHERE order = OLD.id AND done = TRUE) THEN
    RAISE NOTICE 'Cannot delete order that is partially or completely done.';
  ELSE
    RETURN OLD;
  END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

CREATE TRIGGER before_delete_order
  BEFORE DELETE ON order
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE delete_order();
```

Every time you want to delete an order, the function `delete_order()` is called before the actual deletion takes place. If there are any deliveries already done then an error is raised, aborting the deletion. Otherwise `OLD` is returned and the system performs the deletion. This assumes that the deletion of the `order` record cascades to the associated `deliveries`; if not, the trigger function should probably delete those elivery records first in order not to get an FK violation when the order record is deleted.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. So, if I RAISE a notice in my BEFORE DELETE trigger, the **delete** action will be cancelled, and no row affected in the `order` table? Am I right?

Comment: That's correct. See the documentation [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html). If a `DELETE` trigger does not `RETURN OLD` then the operation is cancelled. In the trigger function you never do the operation yourself, the system will do that, but you can modify the process (i.e. insert other data, do an operation on another table) or even cancel it.

Comment: Patrick, your solution works. I just had to change `RAISE NOTICE` to `RAISE EXCEPTION`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using Postgres Rule without triggers

```
create function fn_prevent_deleting(OLD RECORD, tableName text)
returns void as
$BODY$
begin
    //Some condition here
   if (OLD.employee_id is not null) then
     raise exception 'Cant delete row on table %', tableName;
   end if;
end;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql volatile;

CREATE RULE delete_order AS ON DELETE TO orders DO INSTEAD
select fn_prevent_deleting(OLD, 'orders');
```

Comment: Thanks! And where does the part responsible for deleting and checking copndition go? Shall I put `IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM deliveries WHERE order = OLD.id AND done = TRUE)` before raising exception and do the delete operation in `else` clause?

Comment: I've added condition to a pgsql function as example